# Update ValidationSummary after UpdateSource

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm forcing an update of every textBox in a silverlight page:

```
this.txtName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

Everything works fine (the textbox shows its error, etc...) but ValidationSummary is not refreshed...

Any idea??

---

Edit:

After some tests I've realized it was because ValidationSummary wasn't loaded yet. I'll start a new question to ask this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to call the UpdateSource on Loaded page event.

Answer (score 0):

NotifyOnValidationError = “True”?